# Planar UV Mapping?

Tags: uv

Is there a way to do Planar UV mapping that maps front and back side into separate UV islands? In a way that the front side islands are on the left half of the UV map and the back side islands are on the right half of the UV map? The Project From View maps both sides into one island in the center of the UV map.

I'm looking to make simple retro styled UV maps, like in Quake1 and 2.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to create the separate UV islands for each texture. You may unwrap once and assign two textures to one mesh (to both sides of it) using nodes. Set them up as pictured below. 
[image]

Result.
[image]

Comment: @TwinBeast I'm not sure if I fully got the idea of what you want to achieve. If it isn't what you want, please tell me and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Interesting, never thought about using projected UV this way. And the result is so realistic! :)

Comment: @Bithur Yeah, the next gen graphics ;).

Comment: There can be only one texture displayed on a model in the MDL format used by Quake1 engines. For now I used Solid display in the ortho view, then select the faces, UV them, move them a bit in the UV editor, then invert face selection and UV the rest, then position the UVs. Just wanted to know if I could select the whole model and get the same result with one press of a button.